# How do you Download Bloomberg intraday data

Tags: download, bloomberg, blpapi

How do you get intraday 1 minute data from Bloomberg please?
I want bid & ask for 5 futures saved as a data frame please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the Intraday 1-minute bar data, Open, High, Low, Close, etc. You will need to use IntradayBarRequest to //blp/refdata service.

Revised answer:

Send two IntradayBarRequest's, one for BID and the other for ASK event type, with interval = 1 minute to //blp/refdata service. Extract the "Open" element from each data point in response message(s).

```
IntradayBarRequest = {
    security = "IBM UN Equity"
    eventType = BID
    startDateTime = 2019-02-13T00:00:00.000
    endDateTime = 2019-02-14T23:59:59.000
    interval = 1
    gapFillInitialBar = false
    adjustmentNormal = false
    adjustmentAbnormal = false
    adjustmentSplit = false
    adjustmentFollowDPDF = false
}
```

Sample data point:

```
barTickData = {
    time = 2019-02-13T14:30:00.000
    open = 136.45
    high = 136.87
    low = 136.25
    close = 136.76
    volume = 91
    numEvents = 45
    value = 12424.061
}
```

See the IntradayBarExample code example in the SDK.

Comment: Yes. I’m a complete beginner though. Could you help me with code to get bid & ask for esa index please & add it to a df?

Comment: BID and ASK are available in Intraday Ticks, but it's not "1 minute" data as you mentioned. So first please clarify are you looking to get live BID and ASK every 1 minute? or get a 1 minute worth of ticks at any time of the day? Other?

Comment: Hi, it’s historical data I would like for the last 6 months. The opening bid and ask for each minute please.

Comment: How do I do that please?

Comment: See my revised answer above.

Comment: What package is this using please? Sorry, how do you get all the data into a data frame please? Sorry for all of the questions.

Comment: I believe this question was answred in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387868/how-do-i-store-data-from-the-bloomberg-api-into-a-pandas-dataframe/37757763

Comment: Hi,
I tried that link.
I cannot get anything working to download into a df for Python 3.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io):

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp

In [2]: blp.bdib(ticker='SPY US Equity', dt='2019-01-17').tail()
Out[2]:
ticker                    SPY US Equity
field                              open   high    low  close   volume num_trds
time
2019-01-17 15:57:00-05:00        262.82 262.92 262.70 262.88   644947     2744
2019-01-17 15:58:00-05:00        262.87 262.89 262.77 262.86   713451     3152
2019-01-17 15:59:00-05:00        262.87 263.05 262.74 263.00  2248033     5616
2019-01-17 16:09:00-05:00        262.96 262.96 262.96 262.96        0        1
2019-01-17 16:15:00-05:00        262.96 262.96 262.96 262.96        0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan, if you are looking to work with Pandas I would suggest using TIA: https://github.com/bpsmith/tia

You mentioned you are working with Python 3. At the moment, TIA is only compatible with Python 2, but here https://github.com/bpsmith/tia/issues/11 has a Python 3 conversion. I've been using this recently and it's pretty good. An example:

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
import datetime

sid = 'IBM US EQUITY'
event = 'TRADE'
dt = pd.datetools.BDay(-1).apply(pd.datetime.now())
start = pd.datetime.combine(dt, datetime.time(13, 30))
end = pd.datetime.combine(dt, datetime.time(21, 30))
f = LocalTerminal.get_intraday_bar(sid, event, start, end, 
interval=60).as_frame()
f.head(1)

      close     high    low   numEvents   open      time                value   volume
0   162.2500    162.70  161.51  4005    162.4900    2015-02-24 14:30:00  110345672  680888
```

The github link above has loads of examples, too.