# tia library (bloomberg) still print error after PaulMest fork

Tags: python, bloomberg

I have seen many posts re a simple fix of making the library compliant with Python v3.

However, after 4 hours of research, I still cannot fix the issue even after the Paul Mesh solution

1. My python version is 3.8.1
2. I installed pip install tia
3. I ran $ pip install git+git://github.com/PaulMest/tia.git#egg=tia

and I get the below error..

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\YHC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-1c078e856cd8>", line 1, in <module>
    from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal

  File "C:\Users\YHC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tia.bbg.v3api import *

  File "C:\Users\YHC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tia\bbg\v3api.py", line 186
    print 'unhandled event: %s' % evt.EventType
                              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('unhandled event: %s' % evt.EventType)?
```

Can you please help? I think I exhausted my options in Google..!
Thanks much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60714707

Comment: I tried this already, but same errors..can you please help?

Comment: I don't use the python API sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this several years later. I'm guessing that you did not successfully install my fork. I'd suggest uninstalling `tia` and reinstalling it from the fork.

```bash
$ pip uninstall tia
$ pip install git+git://github.com/PaulMest/tia.git#egg=tia
```